# Css grid: area width expand over 100%

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid, and my problem is, that one of the container widths expand over 100%. 
I understand it expands because of the content is larger, but I would like to stay 100%.

Why I need this: Because one field (witch course the problem) I would like to shrink with CSS calc. Problem is that the parent width percentage browser calculates before calc function in the child. This way, even though the field is small at the end when the content size of a parent is calculated is big.

```
.parent {
    grid-area: info_panel;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: $color-card-background;
    margin: 0.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 0.9rem;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
child {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
sub-child { // this is the problem
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: calc(100% - 20rem);
}
```

EDIT

---

```css
.index-page{
  display: grid;
  justify-content: stretch;
  justify-items: stretch;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-columns: 12rem  auto;
  grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 50px - 17rem) 17rem;
  grid-template-areas:  "left_panel     right_panel  "
                        "left_panel     info_panel  ";
}

.panel__left {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
    grid-area: left_panel;
 }

.panel__right {
    background-color: red;
    grid-area: right_panel;
    grid-column: right_panel-start / right_panel-end;
    grid-row: right_panel-start / info_panel-end;
}

.panel__info {
    grid-area: info_panel;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 0.9rem;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

.panel__info__top {
      display: inline-flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.panel__info__top__titles {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: calc(100% - 17rem);
}

.panel__info__top__buttons {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.row_info_text {
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  padding-right: 0.7rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 120%
}

.icon_button {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.icon_button span {
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    color: $color-theme-main;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">

<div class="index-page">
    <div class="panel__left"></div>
    <div class="panel__right"></div>
    <div class="panel__info">
        <div class="panel__info__top">
            <div class="panel__info__top__titles">
                <div class="row_info_text "><b>Small text</b></div>
                <div class="row_info_text">Long text that ruin my layout, because is too long. Long text that ruin my layout, because is too long.Long text that ruin my layout, because is too long.Long text that ruin my layout, because is too long. It is tooooo long</div>
                <div class="row_info_text">small text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel__info__top__buttons">
                <button class="icon_button"><span class="material-icons">assignment_turned_in_outlined</span></button>
                <button class="icon_button"><span class="material-icons">perm_phone_msg</span></button>
                <button class="icon_button"><span class="material-icons">accessibility</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add example HTML to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I add the code snipet

Answer (score 0):

**grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 12rem, 1fr);**

that line should clear up your problem.

Comment: I did use 1fr, but this doesn't work in my example, because it takes content height,... On the left side, I have a table...

Comment: Also, this is not an answer. It is just a general suggestion... Please edit the answer and explain where I should put fr units so that this would work...